Testing disposal of custom dialog
I am testing disposal of a JDialog extension. However, even though I am certain the dialog has no error in that regard, I can't yet get my test to pass. It seems dispose() is invoked, but not on my mock. MRE is below
Why does this test fail and how do I make it pass?
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

class SimpleDialogTest {
    @Test
    void ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed() {
        SimpleDialog dialog = new SimpleDialog();
        SimpleDialog dialogSpy = spy(dialog);
        JButton okButton = dialogSpy.getOkButton();
        okButton.doClick();
        then(dialogSpy).should().dispose();
    }
}

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

public class SimpleDialog extends JDialog {
    private JButton okButton;

    public SimpleDialog() {
        add(createMainPanel());
        add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(createButtonPanelLayout());
        panel.add(createOkButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private LayoutManager createButtonPanelLayout() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        return layout;
    }

    private JButton createOkButton() {
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(e -> dispose());
        return okButton;
    }

    // it's bad practice to provide methods needed by tests only, but for simplicity, I'll do it in this MRE
    public JButton getOkButton() {
        return okButton;
    }
}

Wanted but not invoked:
simpleDialog.dispose();
-> at demos.dialog.SimpleDialogTest.ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed(SimpleDialogTest.java:17)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
simpleDialog.getOkButton();
-> at demos.dialog.SimpleDialogTest.ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed(SimpleDialogTest.java:15)

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

dispose is invoked on real dialog, not spy

A follow-up is here

This fixes it
    @Test
    void ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed() {
        SimpleDialog dialogSpy = spy(SimpleDialog.class);
        JButton okButton = dialogSpy.getOkButton();
        okButton.doClick();
        then(dialogSpy).should().dispose();
    }

However, my real problem is still not fixed as the real dialog is buildable (exposes a builder which is then passed to the dialog's only, private, constructor)

You wrote (in your answer): However, my real problem is still not fixed. I think you should post a new question describing your real problem.

@Abra see the comment

Maybe you should incorporate that comment into the answer? I think that would make it more clear that you have, indeed, posted a separate question.
